# The design of the application in the emulator is different from the preview

Tags: java, android, layout

Created an activity design. Launched id order to check everything. It turned out that the design for the preview is different from the desigh itself in the emulator (Awful gradient and buttons overlap each other).

I am new to this. Help me please.

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aguyd.png)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b875k.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Введите данные"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_UserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Имя пользователя"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Пароль"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_UserName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Login"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Войти"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Register"
        android:layout_width="230sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Регистрация"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: share your layout xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Register" like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Введите данные"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_UserName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Имя пользователя"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Пароль"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_UserName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Login"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Войти"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Register"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Регистрация"`enter code here`
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MainActivity_Button_Login"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainActivity_EditText_Password" />
```

one thing if your device screen is small than overlapping can happen for fix width. you can decrease you width or make it 0dp with proper constraint.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. What should I change now so that everything falls into place?

Comment: Thank you very much